# Fixing REPL completion candidates for wildcard imports

Tags: scala, autocomplete, wildcard, read-eval-print-loop

There is currently a severe REPL limitation:

```
scala> import concurrent._
import concurrent._

scala> Fut<tab>
```

This doesn't complete to `Future`. In other words, wildcard imports are not understood by the `JLineCompletion`.

I am trying to work around this. I am able to find the `ImportHandler` instances which report `importsWildcard == true`, but they are otherwise empty except for the plain `importString` (e.g., `"import concurrent._"`).

How do I get a list of these wildcard imports, so I can fix the completion candidates?

---

One idea is as follows: I can get the completions for `concurrent.<tab>`, so somehow there must be already the functionality to look up the members of a package via the `IMain` instance.

Comment: What version of Scala? `import scala.concurrent.Future` doesn't work on v2.9.1, for example. But importing `util._` and trying to tab-complete .e.g. `Random` works fine for me...ditto for other classes in `scala.concurrent` such as `SyncChannel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't affect current versions of Scala. I tried the sbt console with Scala 2.12.4, and tab completion works with wildcard imports. (Beware of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980459/sbt-console-tab-completion), through).