# sbt console - tab completion

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 1.0.4 (latest as of this writing), and running `sbt console` brings me into the Scala REPL (project uses Scala 2.12.4). What is the keyboard command to invoke code completion? <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work for me, it just adds a tab character and backspace is broken successively. I'm starting sbt from Bash in Linux.

Such that `Indexe<key>` -> `IndexedSeq`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498370/arrow-and-tab-keys-not-working-in-sbt-1-0-3-console). So there is a bug that affects `sbt console`, but one can just run `sbt` and then from the sbt prompt enter `console`, and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> works as expected.

Comment: This is weird. You may want to report it upstream in scala/bug.

Comment: This bug no longer exists (sbt 1.4 currently)